# When to use Nancy StaticConfiguration.DisableMethodNotAllowedResponses

Tags: http, nancy

We recently changed some Nancy routes, and had a test fail with a 405 MethodNotAllowed.

After debugging through Nancy we came across the StaticConfiguration.DisableMethodNotAllowedResponses property. Setting this to true means the test fails with a 404.

My question is, when / why is it preferable to return 405 rather than 404? I can understand this makes sense if for example you tried to POST to a route which only supports GET, however I don't think that is the same as our scenario.

Before route change:

```
Get["/web/api/somepath/{param1}/{param2}"]
Post["/web/api/somepath/{param1}"]
```

After route change:

```
Get["/web/api/somepath/{param1}/{param2}"]
Post["/web/api/somepath/{param1}/{param2}"]
```

Our (out of date) test is POSTing to `/web/api/somepath/param1Value`

Maybe this is just an edge case related to how Nancy scores route matches?

Additional note: I noticed in DefaultRouteResolver.Resolve() when the following line runs, allowedMethods contains only GET (I am not able to debug into the RouteResolverTrie code for some reason):

var allowedMethods = this.trie.GetOptions(pathDecoded, context).ToArray();

(To clarify, I would expect allowedMethods to contain GET and POST).